# guard let with logical operators

Tags: swift

How can I use guard let like:

```
guard let value = vm.value1 || let value = vm.value2 else { return }
```

I need to check value1, If it has value, continue to work with it, else check value2, and work with it, else: quit. Only one can have value.

Comment: `guard let value = vm.value1 ?? vm.value2 else { return }`? You don't need to know if the value is coming from property `value1` or `value2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The semantics you are describing seems to be:

```
guard let value = vm.value1 ?? vm.value2 else { return }
```

If `vm.value1` is not nil, `value` would be bound to its value, and the code after the `guard` statement would be executed.

Otherwise, if `vm.value2` is not nil, `value` would be bound to its value, and the code after the `guard` statement would be executed.

Otherwise, `return` would be executed.

---

Similarly, multiple `let`s could be used to achieve something similar to the semantics of the logical "AND":

```
guard let value1 = vm.value1, let value2 = vm.value2 else { return }
```

The code after the `guard` statement is only executed if `vm.value1` is not nil, *and* `vm.value2` is not nil, and `value1` and `value2` are bound to the corresponding values.

Also note that you can mix arbitrary boolean conditions with the `let` bindings too:

```
guard let value = vm.value1, someBool || someOtherBool else { return }
```

Comment: Thanks! problem is that value1 and value2 are different types, but i need only one. I can't use ?? operator in this case. I need one of them to display on tableview

Comment: @AlisherBaigazin Well what is the type of `cell.value`? To be able to do `cell.value = value`, `value` has to have one single type. You just have to convert the expressions on both sides of `??` to that type.

Comment: @AlisherBaigazin If they are of different types, you can't use one guard and you'll need different code in each case anyway. Best to use an `if let ... else if let ... else { return }`

Comment: Okay, if you want to set different properties of `cell`, then just check a boolean condition in the `guard`, like `value1 != nil || value2 != nil`, and use an `if let ... else if let` to set `cell.value1`/`cell.value2`. Please do not edit your question in such away that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @Sweeper can you clarify this moment "check a boolean condition in the guard, like value1 != nil || value2 != nil"?

Comment: @AlisherBaigazin I just realised I didn't actually type the word `guard`. I meant `guard value1 != nil || value2 != nil else { return }`.

Comment: Maybe you should have an enum with associated value to handle `value1` and `value2` on cell instead of having two properties... Else, you might want to use two `if let {} else if let {} else { return }`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use logical operator with guard statement
But there is another way of performing AND operator

```
guard let value = vm.value1,
  let value = vm.value2 else {
      return
}
```

And OR operator functionality can be achieve by using ternary operator with guard statement

```
guard let value = ((vm.value1 != nil) ? vm.value1 : vm.value2 else {
      return
}
```

And you can use the value after else statement